# Deformat Discord Text

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have been trying to make a "deformatting" function that escapes all formatting characters (*,`,_,|,~) and I have actually created this, but I want to check if the user already escaped it to prevent formatting happening on accident.

My current function:

```js
function deformat(string) {
  return string.replace(/([*_~|`])/g, '\\$1');
}
```

I would love to be able to improve it so that a string like `"\*hey\*"` doesn't become `"\\*hey\\*"`, which would italicize it. (Note that the slashes are not escaped in the previous two string for readability)

Comment: Short answer: use a negated lookbehind and lookahead in your Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function deformat(string) {
  return string.replace(/(?<!\\)([*_~|`])/g, '\\$1');
}

console.log(deformat('*hey*'));
console.log(deformat('\*hey\*'));
```

---

#### Edit:

Since the above didn't work, try this:

```js
function deformat(string) {
  return string.replace(/(^|[^\\])([*_~|`])/g, '$1\\$2');
}

console.log(deformat('*hey*'));
console.log(deformat('\*hey\*'));
```

It uses `(^|[^\\])`, which matches the start of the string or anything that isn't '\', instead of a negative lookbehind.

Comment: Well, that didn't work, and I'm going to guess it was because `$1` refers to the negative lookbehind or something like that, or stacksnippets is not running the right version of javascript.

One thing I would love to know is, is it possible to kind of "nest" that check so that it is impossible to format the output, or is that wishful thinking

Comment: @winter_sand Lookbehinds are only [available in node v9.11.2 and up](https://node.green/#ES2018-features--RegExp-Lookbehind-Assertions). What version of node are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Node v13.5.0, so that isn't the problem. I can use this solution it is just exploitable if someone really wants to try.